# How to remove /n from a list while printing or putting into an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, newline

I'm using the following code to split up a large text file into chunks of `100`.

```
import itertools
import pprint

with open('usernames.txt') as f:
    while True:
        lines = list(itertools.islice(f, 100))  # similar to `f[0:100]`
        if not lines:
            break

        print lines
```

However when I print, every line has a `/n` of course, now I was wondering on how to rid of them.

As `lines.rstrip('/n')` does not work, neither does `.remove()`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `/n` is not an escape sequence.  It is just the characters `/` and `n`.  A newline in Python is represented by `\n`.  For more information, see [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in the documentation.

To remove the newlines from the items in the list, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lines = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in itertools.islice(f, 100)]
```

Comment: forgive my typo, but it gives the same results.

Comment: your edit worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help as well:

```
line.replace('\n','').replace('\r','');
```

Comment: It would be even better if you explained why it would help and what it would do.